# Website with Facebook Callback URL for login through Passport

Tags: javascript, facebook, passport-facebook

I'm having trouble understanding what is the right configuration for the Facebook callback URL for authentication through Passport-Facebook strategy.
This is for a MEAN/Javascript project. In development mode, the callback worked fine, and we had it as http://localhost:8000/oauth/Facebook/callback.
I recently launched the website here: http://52.25.45.148 and added it as the Site URL in the Facebook Developer page under Settings > Website.
However, when I can't get any of the combinations of callback URL to be synchronized with that setting.
I've tried: 
 
 http://

- 52.25.45.148:8000/oauth/Facebook/callback
- 52.25.45.148/oauth/Facebook/callback
- 52.25.45.148:8000/#!/oauth/Facebook/callback
- 52.25.45.148/#!/oauth/Facebook/callback

Does anyone have any insight into this? I'd be so grateful.

Also it currently says that my app is in development mode, but since we deployed- how do we change it to production mode?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK you can not use IP addresses, it has to be a domain name.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I bought a domain, we-bucketlist.com. But it still doesn't work with Facebook callback. 
Are there configurations I'm missing?

Comment: Fill out the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field in app settings.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I didn't restart the pm2 server so the new configuration didn't kick in. -_-